# iOS UITableView instance variable?

Tags: ios, tableview, instance-variables

I'm building an app with a UITableView and search function. But when I try to reload the UITableView with this code:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

The property UITableView is not found. I'm new to iOS but I think the instance variable of the UITableView is wrong. How/where do I declare of find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.tableView is a derived instance variable if the base class is UITableViewController

Check the doc...
[UITableViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewController/tableView)

Comment: ...Controller. You missed a bit!

Comment: My base class is UIViewController do I have to change this or is there an other way to do this?

Comment: If you are using a NIB your will have to connect the tableView property to the view

Comment: Like I sad I'm new to IOS can you tell me how to do this I'm using a NIB? Thx for your help so far btw.

Comment: If you create new view controller with a NIB, that subclasses UITableViewController instead of UIViewController, it should do the linking in the NIB for you ;)

Comment: But I have a custom made header and footer, this way de listview will fill the complete screen. Can I connect it myself in the base class is UIViewController?

Comment: Ok I've found the solution using the following tutorial: http://www.aboveground.com/tutorials/adding-a-uitableview-to-a-custom-uiview

Now I have set-up a IBOutlet and connected it to the tableview, it's working now. Thx for your help craig1231